# Locating a process in a linux vm (it's complicated)

Tags: linux, docker, ps

I have a virtualbox vm to which I can connect through a browser using localhost:8080. The network of the vm is NAT with port forwarding of localhost:8080 to vm:8080.

However, logging into the console of that vm as root and running netstat shows no process listening on 8080. I guess there is some kind of virtualisation going on here. The company which created this vm is using docker in some projects, but there doesn't seem to be docker installed. The other technology they use sometimes is xen, but xm is missing, too. What's even stranger is that /proc/self/cgroup is empty.

How can I win this game of hide and seek?

Comment: Can you try to establish a connection from outside and monitor on which port that connection acts, looking for the (known) process instead for the port?

Comment: You wrote `netstat` meaning `netstat -l`, right? In my Debian it omits listening sockets by default.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it helps finding the process

```
sudo netstat -avpe --numeric-hosts --numeric-ports 2> /dev/null| grep :{port number}
```

create a script e.g. `check-port` and set permissions

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(sudo netstat -avpe --numeric-hosts --numeric-ports 2> /dev/null| grep :$                                                                                                 1)"
echo -e "$s"
```

Usage:

> check-port [port number]

Answer (score 0):

In general the guest firewall may redirect the port. Try:

```
sudo iptables -nL | grep 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

The port forwarding is done on VirtualBox side.

When you connect to port 8080 to your vm, you most probably connect to a port opened on your real OS.

Check this answer on how this is defined on virtualbox:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537751/virtualbox-port-forward-from-guest-to-host